# How to reset program after it has given the answer

Tags: java, reset

Hi i have my basic code done for Triangle area calculating with help of a guide. Then i added little code to make it more fun but i want it to reset after you get the outcome. I want the program to reset to "Enter the triangle's base: " after it has completed previous calculation with valid value. It would be good if it would reset after (x) amout of time.

Simply i want it to press C button in imaginary calculator after the task is done.

Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
public class TriangleArea {

static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
public static void main(String[] args) 
{

    //declare variables to hold the base and height
    double base;
    double height;
    //Variables created. move on
    System.out.print("Enter the triangle's base: ");
    base = sc.nextDouble();
    //Base has been declared and filled in
    System.out.print("Enter the triangle's height: ");
    height = sc.nextDouble();
    //Both variables are filled in
    double preArea = base * height;
    //now we need to divide by 2
    double Area = preArea / 2;
    //There we go. All variables are done, area has been calculated.
    System.out.println("The area of your triangle is: " + Area);

    int Outcome;

      if (Area <= 100) {
          System.out.println("Triangle's area is small");
      }

      if (Area <= 300) {
          System.out.println("Triangles size is medium");

      }
      if (Area >= 300) {
          System.out.println("Triangle's area is big");
      }

      else {

      }       

    }
 }
```

Comment: What do you mean by _"reset"_?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow Ale - I edited your post and removed `javascript` as a tag. Keep in mind `Java` and `JavaScript` are two completely separate languages.

Comment: @lealceldeiro when program starts it says "Enter the triangle's base:" this is where i want it to reset to after the outcome has been calculated. Timer would be good too so that the reset would happen after given amount of time.

Comment: Thank you @zfrisch

Comment: You probably want to surround the code by a while loop that exits e.g., by having the user enter 'X' or another exit code. You can use a `boolean` that is initialized to `true` and gets set to `false` when the user enters the exit code. Hope this is what you are after. You're post is not entirely clear.

Comment: Agree with @MWB. You should clarify  if this is what you want. It's too broad up to now, IMO.

Comment: @MWB Hi, as i stated in earlier comment i want it to reset to the starting point of program after the outcome has been calculated with valid value.

Comment: @MWB   I edited it so its more clear now.

Comment: Also, your logic fails. A triangle can now be both small and medium at the same time! You want to use `if (Area <= 300 && Area > 100)` (or you could use else if statements).

Comment: @MWB Still it works with my code :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use a while loop that exits e.g., by having the user enter '0' as an exit code. You can use a `boolean` that is initialized to true and gets set to false when the user enters the exit code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        boolean repeat = true;
        while (repeat) {
            // declare variables to hold the base and height
            double base;
            double height;
            // Variables created. move on
            System.out.print("Enter the triangle's base (enter 0 to exit): ");
            base = sc.nextDouble();
            if (base == 0) {
                repeat = false;
                break;
            }
            // Base has been declared and filled in
            System.out.print("Enter the triangle's height (enter 0 to exit): ");
            height = sc.nextDouble();
            if (height == 0) {
                repeat = false;
                break;
            }
            // Both variables are filled in
            double preArea = base * height;
            // now we need to divide by 2
            double Area = preArea / 2;
            // There we go. All variables are done, area has been calculated.
            System.out.println("The area of your triangle is: " + Area);

            if (Area <= 100) {
                System.out.println("Triangle's area is small");
            }

            if (Area <= 300) {
                System.out.println("Triangles size is medium");

            }
            if (Area >= 300) {
                System.out.println("Triangle's area is big");
            }

            else {

            }

        }
        System.out.println("Bye bye");
}
}
```

Comment: I modified your suggestion so that you put "0" to base and not to height.

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to do

```
while (true){

    your code 

    if (exit condition){
        break;
    }
}
```

This way your program will loop.

Comment: This did reset it to starting position but it didnt remove the previous colculation.